# Отображение скачиваемого файла под Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Собственно загвозка в следующем, есть следующий код который прекрасно скачивает файл в папку Downloads

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(myUrl);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setTitle(mPicture);
            request.setDescription(mPicture);
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, mPicture);

            Log.d(TAG, mPicture);


            long refid = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Сам файл я наблюдаю в папке Dowmloads под правильным названием и нужным мне названием. Далее пытаюсь этот файл отобразить в ImageView

```
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + File.separator + mPicture);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

И получаю ошибку:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Download/Article_168720_860_575.jpg (No such file or directory)

Сразу скажу, что код у меня не последовательный. И отображение картинки происходит после гарантированного скачивания картинки. Пробовал как на Android 9.0 версии так и на 4.4. При указании абсолютного пути все работает на ура. Но как я понимаю от устройства к устройства он может менять и поэтому это не выход.

Comment: Абсолютный путь разве такой, как в ошибке? Там наверняка еще что-то есть перед Download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` - эта константа обозначает тип папки (категорию), но не содержит путь к ней. Путь нужно получать методом `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS))`.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
File imageFile = new File(dir, mPicture);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

P.S. разработчики Андроида почему-то хотят искоренить прямой доступ к файлам за пределами приватных папок приложения и как я понял этот код на Андроид 10 работать не будет.

Comment: Бинго! Спасибо!!!